# Including an r5rs file into another file in racket

Tags: scheme, sicp, racket

One of my courses is using DrRacket for some sections of SICP. We're working on the metacircular evaluator and I have an R5RS code file (`set-car!` and `set-cdr!`) which I need to use with my work. Because the R5RS file is roughly 500 lines, I'd prefer to keep it in a separate buffer. How can I include it into my answer buffer's defintions? It appears `racket/include` requires `#lang racket`, but `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` are not in that language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Write the module in *#lang r5rs*, and add the following after the lang line:

   ```
   (#%provide (all-defined))
   ```
2. Have your answer buffer also in *#lang r5rs*, and use *#%require* to pull in its definitions:

   ```
   (#%require "some-module.ss")
   ```

For example, if I have an *f1.ss* with the following content:

```
#lang r5rs
(#%provide (all-defined))
(define (f x)
  (* x x))
```

and an *f2.ss* with the following content:

```
#lang r5rs
(#%require "f1.ss")
(display (f 3))
(display (f 4))
```

then if I run *f2.ss*, it does the appropriate thing in displaying 916, and its Interactions buffer will know about all the definitions written in *f1.ss*.

This uses the Racket-specfic low-level module importing stuff mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-mod.html#%28part._.Non-.R5.R.S_.Bindings_from_r5rs%29).  Good luck!

Comment: This also works if you're using `#lang sicp`.